# OpenGL - Texture origin is top-left

Tags: user-interface, opengl, textures, lwjgl

I have a little problem:
I know that in UVs, the origin (0, 0) is at the bottom left.

I advanced in the discovery of opengl (I use lwjgl 3), and I wanted to make an interface.
In my opinion, I just need to display a texture that includes the text to display a button.
So I created, as usual, a new shader (vertexShader + fragmenShader).

But by great surprise, my texture is upside down! Why?
It's very weird.

this is my vertexShader:

```
#version 330

in vec3 position;
in vec2 texCoords;

out vec2 pass_texCoords;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1);
    pass_texCoords = texCoords;
}
```

This is my fragmentShader:

```
#version 330

in vec2 pass_texCoords;

out vec4 out_Color;
uniform sampler2D texSampler;

void main() {

    out_Color = texture(texSampler, pass_texCoords);
}
```

This is how I create my vao
(for the moment I plan to display a triangle):

```
my vetrices : -0.5, 0.5, 0, -0.5, -0.5, 0, 0.5, -0.5, 0
my texCoords : 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0
my indices : 0, 1, 2
```

And now how I display it:

```
 //bind shader, bind VAO, enable VBOs
 GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
 GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
 GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
 //disableVBOs, unbind VAO, unbind shader
```

My triangle looks like (but the texture inside is inverted) :

```
      |  \
      |    \
      |      \
      |_________
```

Need more code?
I know how invert the texture manually, but I think that the best way is to find the problem...

But if someone know how add an user-interface in a better way, I'm more than interrested!

Comment: @httpdigest I've never had a problem with textures before. I tested with several types of images, PNGs, JPGs, and also create images myself with bufferedImages... But here, my texture is upside down. But thanks for this link

Comment: Maybe you can flip the texture horizontally, or invert the 'v' coordinate, where u = u and v = 1 - v